# Implication of integrability

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(A,\mathcal{F},\mu)$. We say that a real measurable function $f$ on $A$ is integrable if $\int_A \mid f\mid d\mu < \infty$.

Show that if $f$ is integrable, then $f$ is measurable.

Is it really always true? I read about distinctions of existence and finiteness, so these bring issues if the statement is always true.

So far, from the integrability as defined above, I concluded that $f^+,f^-$ must be integrable (finite). What's next?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried showing that $f$ is not measurable implies $f$ is not integrable?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense... How do you define integrability of $f$ if $f$ is not measurable in the first place ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Gabriel. Your definition of integrability already assumes measurability. If you don't assume that part then take any unmeasurable subset $A$ of $[0, 1]$ and let 
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}\ x \in A \\ -1 & \text{if}\ x \not \in A, x \in [0, 1] \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}. $$
Then $f$ is not measurable but $\lvert f \rvert = \chi_{[0, 1]}$ (the indicator function of $[0, 1]$) and hence $f$ would be integrable by your definition, thus is a counterexample.

Comment: The indicator function $\chi_A$ is not measurable. A question, why $\mid f\mid=\chi_{[0,1]}$?

Comment: $f$ just take values $\pm 1$ on $[0, 1]$, so taking the absolute value makes it take the value $1$ on $[0, 1]$

Comment: Oh, now I realize the functionality of this $2\chi_A$ there. You are right!

Comment: I agree with you, I've rewritten it to make what $f$ is more obvious

Comment: Interestingly, I thought your previous version more direct and intuitive. :)

Comment: A question: did you assume $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where the domain space contains the Lebesgue $\sigma$-field with the Lebesgue measure? f would be integrable if $\mu([0,1])<\infty$ which I don't know that holds for every measure. Another concern is the existence of such $A\subseteq [0,1]$, maybe the irrationals.

Comment: The definition needs to hold for general measures so any single counterexample would do. Existence of an immeasurable subset of $[0, 1]$ in the Lebesgue or Borel $\sigma$-algebra is covered in most measure theory textbooks (see the Vitali set). Also my counterexample is not the important flaw in trying to prove integrability implies measurability, the fact that we haven't even defined the integral for non-measurable functions is. If we simply set $f =  \chi_A$ then what would $\int \lvert f \rvert \, \text{d}\mu$ even be? Measurability must be assumed to even define the integral.